# Error occurs if I do not make every class static in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to java. I'm learning java from a youtube course. There the instructor makes classes just by using the "class" keyword. But whenever I try to do that, an error occurs and I have to add the keyword "static" before the class to solve the error. Should I add "static" keyword everytime I make a class? I have to add static even during inheriting the class.

[Here we can see error is occured without the keyword "static"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b7YT.png)

[The error goes away after I add the keyword "static"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8nGT.png)

Should I add the keyword "static" everytime I make a class?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve] of your code, and include it *as text*, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

No.

`main` has to be static. static is more or less an advanced concept; if you don't want to learn about it yet (probably a good idea), the fix is simple: Get out of `static` IMMEDIATELY. This is not difficult:

```
public class MyApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new MyApp().go();
  }

  void go() throws Exception {
    // this is where you write your code
  }
}
```

Other than the one `static` in your `main` method, don't put static anywhere. You won't have any 'uhoh that is not static' errors any more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting all your classes in the same file (not a standard thing), and you are using those classes from your `void static main()` method, then yes, you will need to put `static` in front of your classes.

Normally classes would be in their own file, and then you would not use (actually, could not use) static in front of the `class` keyword.

Comment: ohhh okay thankyou I understood it now. I'm just learning java so I put all the classes in the same file.